# How to use <p:ajax> to pass javascript generated data to backing bean?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a js-function `codeAddress()` that processess the data from `address` and updates the values of `fullAddress` and `validField`.
I tried `<p:ajax>` to pass the data of `fullAddress` and `validField` to the backing bean, but the setter methods seem to get called one request delayed.

```
<h:form id="addressForm">
    <p:inputText id="address">
        <p:ajax onstart="codeAddress()" process="fullAddress validField"/>
    </p:inputText>
    <p:commandButton value="submit" />
    <p:inputText id="fullAddress" value="#{addressBean.fullAddress}" />
    <p:inputText id="validField" value="#{addressBean.valid}" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: Before submit I want javascript to process the data from `address` and updates `fullAddress` and `validField`.  
Then I want the new values of `fullAddress` and `validField` to get submitted to the backing bean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onstart` is invoked *right before* the ajax request is about to be sent. At that moment the ajax request is already prepared for long. It's thus too late to let it to take the changed input values into account.

Better use the input component's `onchange` attribute instead. It's invoked before the ajax request is to be prepared.

```
<p:inputText id="address" onchange="codeAddress()">
    <p:ajax process="fullAddress validField"/>
</p:inputText>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although it sounds senseful the behavior seems unchanged despite a server restart and cleared browser cache... in chrome.
In Firefox your solution work for me perfectly right now. :)
Hope it will stay like that. :D

Comment: Works for me in Chrome. Sure that your JS isn't broken?

Comment: I have an `alert()` right at the end of the JS, which gets executed in both browsers. Could the strange behavior still be a broken JS?

Comment: There was indeed an issue with the JS: [Javascript and <p:ajax> behave strange](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14857860/javascript-and-pajax-behave-strange)